# iOS - rotating an UIImageView based on X,Y orientation

Tags: ios, uiimageview, trigonometry

I've subclassed a UIView as an avatar-object, which contains an icon (UIImageView), name (UILabel) and ID (UILabel). Depending on the orientation X,Y coordinates, I want the icon to be rotated. For example, say orientation.X = 1 and orientation.Y = 1 would give 45 degrees angle. X and Y could be anything between -1 and 1.

I'm not sure how it is calculated mathematically nor the cocoa API calls for it. Any ideas where to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for smoothness i added an animation:

```
- (void)rotateView:(UIView *)view withDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration andRadians:(CGFloat)radians
{
    // Setup the animation
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

    // The transform matrix
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians);
    view.transform = transform;

    // Commit the changes
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

EDIT:

for other angles you need to create your own rotation matrix.

[How rotation matrix works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)

Read [here](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/demystifying-cgaffinetransform.html) how to create a custom affine transformation in Objective-c

Hope this helps.

Comment: I dont want the image to be rotated around the center as it screws up the image

Comment: I added my post, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into the trigonometric functions - specifically `acos` and `asin`.

[This article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle#Trigonometric_functions_on_the_unit_circle) may be helpful.